# How to skip first, last non-blank line and blank lines from modification in a file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file something like this:

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845

849002|48|1208004|100|||1

849007|28|1208004|100|||1

T|2|3
```

Note that there are extra empty lines at the end of the file.

I want to replace the value of column 5 with column 4's value in all the lines except first and last non-blank line.

I cannot rely on the number of fields as the last line may have as many fields as the other ones, nor on the lines to modify always starting with a number.

I tried the code below:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS="|"} {$5=$4; print}' in.txt
```

Output is:

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|1|20130215035845
||||
849002|48|1208004|100|100||1
||||
849007|28|1208004|100|100||1
||||
T|2|3||
||||
||||
||||
```

Expected output:

```
H|ACCT|XEC|1|TEMP|20130215035845|

849002|48|1208004|100|100||1

849007|28|1208004|100|100||1

T|2|3
```

How can I skip the first and last non-blank lines from getting changed? I also want  to skip blank lines.

Comment: How can we know the last line? Will there always be the same number of lines? Your output suggests that your input file has several blank lines at the end.

Comment: @terdon : Max will be 3 blank line in the last, that is the main challenge. In question from last line I mean that line which is not blank in the last.

Comment: ok... from your sample only lines starting with a number require to be changed... can that be used in solution? because restricting last non-blank line is not trivial

Comment: @Sundeep: No, that can't be used. First line and last non-blank line can also be start with number.

Comment: @don_crissti yup that would make logic easier :)

Comment: @αғsнιη: _Is always your last non-blank has less fields than previous ones?_ No, it can have less or more or equal fields.

Comment: @don_crissti the OP specified that the number of fields is variable and cannot be used to infer anything. Your approach would still work, just not by using field number. But why don't you post it?

Comment: @don_crissti ah yes, indeed. I meant that you cannot rely on the fact that a line has fewer fields to define the last non-empty line. I had thought that was what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go with `awk` and processing the file only once.

```bsh
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print;next} m && NF{print m}
    NF{l="\n"$0; $5=$4; m="\n"$0; c=0}; !NF{c++}
END{ print l; for (; i++<c;)print }' OFS='|' infile
```

**Explanation:**

Here we are skyping first line to being replace 5<sup>th</sup> field's value with 4<sup>th</sup> field's value, and just print it and do `next`.

... if it (current next line) was not empty line (at least contains one field `NF`), then take a backup of whole line with a `\n`ewline added `l="\n"$0` first next set 5<sup>th</sup> field's value with 4<sup>th</sup> field's value `$5=$4` and last set it to a variable `m` with a `\n`ewline added `m="\n"$0;`; There is a `c` variable as a *counter* flag and is used to determine the number of empty lines `!NF{c++}` if no line with at least one field seen; Otherwise `c=0` will reset this counter.

Now we have modified line in `m` variable and `m && NF{print m}` will print it where in the next step `awk` runs and `m` has set and it's not on empty lines `& NF` (this is used to prevent duplication on printing when empty line).

At the end we are printing the untouched last line which we take backup every time before performing replacement `END{ print l; ...` and then number of empty lines which never seen a line with a field with looping `for (; i++<c;)print }'`.

That's much shorter if you don't need redundant empty lines.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print;next} m && NF{print m}
    NF{l=$0; $5=$4; m=$0} END{ print l}' OFS='|' infile
```

Comment: First code is not changing the value.

Comment: Hi @serenesat It is changing! Both codes does the changes.

Comment: Nope. second one is changing but not the first one. First one doesn't make any change and also doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, relying on the second line being blank:

```
sed '1{n;d;};/./!{H;$g;$p;d;};x;s/|/\n/4;s/\([^|]*\)\n[^|]*/\1|\1/'
```

If your `sed` doesn't understand `\n` in the replacement, use a literal newline instead (or use a character known not to be part of the file).

Explanation:

Lines (except for the first one) get collected in the hold space, when the end of the file is reached, the hold space is printed as is, otherwise with the desired replacement.

In detail:

- `1{n;d;}`: For the 1st line, `n` prints it unchanged reading the next line, just to `d`elete it. Why? Because the hold space is to contain something to be printed, so it contains an empty line anyhow.
- `/./!{H;$g;$p;d;}` is executed for empty lines only, appending itself to the `H`old space. Only for the last line `$` move the hold space back and print it. In any case `d`elete to stop further executing for this line.
- `x` exchanges the non-empty line with the hold buffer, so it is kept there, while we can now process the saved lines, because we know it was not the last not-empty one.
- `s/|/\n/4;s/\([^|]*\)\n[^|]*/\1|\1/` performs copying from column 4 to 5 by replacing the fourth `|` with a newline to mark it and then replace the fields before and after the match with two times the field before.

Comment: Nice! And yes, please explain that. This sort of complex sed commands look like Asterix swearing.

Comment: I like the term "Asterix swearing", although it better fits to some crazy languages on *code golfing*. Anyhow, added the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

As I said, the easiest way is to process the file twice.
1st pass - get the line no. for the last non-empty line.
2nd pass - process all lines (except the header) before that last non-empty line that have at least five fields:

```
awk -F'|' -vc=0 'NR==FNR{if (NF){c=NR};next};
FNR>1 && NF>4 && FNR<c {$5=$4};1' OFS='|' infile infile
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption, what if the line have only four columns - the fifth column should be added, with fourth column's value. Right?

#### First version - awk is used

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = "|";
    OFS = "|";
} 
FNR == NR && $0 {
    last = NR;
}
FNR != NR {
    if(NF > 3 && FNR != last && FNR != 1) {
        $5 = $4;
    }
    print;
}' input.txt input.txt
```

**Same code with comments:**

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = "|";
    OFS = "|";
} 
# The first traversing through file
# It is needed for getting the number of the last, non-empty line
FNR == NR && $0 {
    last = NR;
}
# The second traversing through file
FNR != NR {
    # if the number of fields more than 3 (therefore, the fourth column exists)
    # and the line number of the current file is not the last and not the first. 
    if(NF > 3 && FNR != last && FNR != 1) {
        $5 = $4;
    }
    print;
}' input.txt input.txt
```

#### Second version - sed and tac are used

```
tac input.txt | 
sed '
1,/./!{
    $!{
        s/\(|\w*\)/\1\1/3
        s/|\w*//5
    }
}' | tac
```

**Explanation:**

1. `tac` - concatenate and print files in reverse. `tac` is a `cat` in reverse.
2. `1,/./!` - skip lines from the first to the first non-empty (including).
3. `$!` - all lines except the last. Remember that we flipped the file, and the last line is the first line in fact.
4. `s/\(|\w*\)/\1\1/3` - duplicating the fourth column. I decided use `\w` instead of `[^|]` for beauty. But you can change it, if non-word characters are expected in the fields.
5. `s/|\w*//5` - removes the former fifth column (now it is sixth).
6. `| tac` - flips the file back.